# How can I trim the display of text and expand with "more" link?

Tags: 7

On my user profile page I have a "about me" text field that can get pretty long.
I would like to only show about 200 characters of text with a "more" link.
When you click more it would show the rest of the text, ideally on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, up in the sky.  It's a bird.  It's a plane.  It's...... sorry.  This is a job for jQuery. A quick google of "jquery more less toggle" (without the quotes lol) will show lots of examples.

Comment: that's funny. I haven't spent much time with jquery but it seems that it's time to get my feet wet. I had hoped there would be a small module or a setting in views that would do the trick ;-)